# About Physics and philosophy

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to ask if there is a room for questions regarding physics and philosophy:

1) On an epistemological basis

2) On a purely philosophical basis, that is, questions about the connection of physics with philosophical thinking(for example a question about consciousness and Martin Heidegger or Wittgenstein or a question regarding the phenomenology of thermodynamics and it' s connection to phenomenology or existentialism).

If the answer is partly yes, what is the type of questions i have the right to ask?

Thank you.

Comment: More on Philosophy: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/80/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/821/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5087/2451

Comment: Is the subject still under discussion?

Comment: As I see one of the two questions is closed and the other not. Some are arguing that there should be allowed such questions and some the opposite, but allow me to say that it seems to me as a philosophical kind of arguing- whether physics is or isn't philosophy is at the level of discussion a subject of understanding(regarding the questions)

Comment: @Qmechanic       Isn't always an ontological or for science a knowlegde of theory problem how we enter knowledge and how we interpret it? From that point of view, doesn't philosophical questions apply to physics, to how we, as scientist understand our work?
Thank you.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6284/50583

Comment: the [chat] area is open for discussion as a more freeform alternative to the rigorous/ delineated main sites & has seen some bordering-on-philosophical threads despite it being downplayed (to say the least) by many regulars. separate rooms can be created & have had some moderate success in that area also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm inclined to say no, such questions are generally off topic here. Some of them may fit on [Philosophy Stack Exchange](//philosophy.stackexchange.com).